# Is it possible to use Google Adsense in a PWA/Trusted Web Activity app?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, ads, adsense, trusted-web-activity

A general question about integrating Adsense into a PWA/Trusted Web Activity app - Is it currently possible to use? If so, where to get started?

Copied from: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa/issues/105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Trusted Web Activity will open the PWA in a browser tab that is fullscreen. The same APIs used for regular websites and Progressive Web Apps will work inside the Trusted Web Activity without any changes.

The [Adsense page](https://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/adsense/start/) is the best place to get started. Also make sure the application meets the [Adsense program policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/topic/1261918?hl=en&ref_topic=1250104).

Comment: The technical requirements in Adsense policies clearly mentions that App developers wishing to monetize by publishing AFC and AdX display ads through a WebView must use a custom Tab. But the latest version of bubblewrap comes with the new android-browser-helper. Let me make it simple for you, Can I use AdSense with latest version of bubblewrap??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a few years ago, I think "technically" you could use Adsense, but there are multiple stories of websites getting rejected and/or impressions simply crashing, esp. if combined with AMP. Some of the conflicting experiences are linked here:

https://slickstack.io/forum/topic/monetizing-pwa-app-options-google-adsense-allowed-or-not

(Disclaimer, I'm the lead dev of SlickStack community.)

However, a recent study by Progressier claims that Adsense is now one of the best ways to monetize PWA apps, and also mentions other options too. It seemse that it's better supported now:

https://progressier.com/best-ad-networks-to-monetize-pwa

> Google AdSense would probably be our default choice to monetize a PWA.
> If your app is used by developers, Carbon Ads and Ezoic are solid
> choices to get in front of the right advertisers. For news PWAs,
> Media.net and Mediavine are good options provided you have a large
> enough audience.